# MS Excel, Macro appending extra characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Using a macro, I'm joining 2 separate sets of columns with a colon using a simple function, like  `=A2&":"&B2`

This works fine until it gets to the final row, where the macro is adding two additional cells each with just `:` in them.  It looks like the macro auto-selected past the fields that contained data and joined the empty cell contents with the `:`.

I've reviewed the macro several times and don't see what might be causing it.  Can someone spot check this for me?

```
Sub NetworkStatisticsFilter()
'

' NetworkStatisticsFilter Macro
' Format and Filter Data from Get-NetStatTCP to simplify port discovery
'

'
'Suppress alerts
'
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'
'Delete empty header rows that resulted from Get-NetStatTCP export
'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

'
'Text-to-Columns, space-delimited
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'
'Join LocalAddress & LocalPort with a ":" then copy results and replace both columns w/a paste-value
'
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SRC"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&"":""&RC[-1]"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C77")
    Range("C2:C77").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

'
'Join RemoteAddress & RemotePort with a ":" then copy results and replace both columns w/a paste-value
'
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DST"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&"":""&RC[-1]"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D77")
    Range("D2:D77").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("B:D").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

'
'Auto-fit columns
'
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'
'Auto-filter loopback address/port combinations and delete resulting rows
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$79").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=127.0.0.1*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

'
'Remove duplicate values in DST column
'
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$67").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9

'
'Allow Alerts
'
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Comment: My initial thought would be that there's some extra blank spaces being imported in - There's is a difference between an empty and a blank cell in Excel. I'd consider writing the code to see how many lines of data you have, then only doing that many lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying formula in columns using `Range.AutoFill()`. Thus, if the macro is creating formula in wrong cells that means the range you are providing is false. You are using `Range("C2:C77")`, the real one may be `Range("C2:C76")` for example.

You can find the last used row in a range (here C column) using this :

```
LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Furthermore when you delete empty headers you are :

(a) Deleting row 1

(b) Deleting row 2 which is row 3 before (a) was executed.

Is that on purpose ? If you wanted to delete first and second row you can do that :

```
Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Delete
```

**EDIT:**

As you indeed wanted to delete row 1 and 3 :

```
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify to use the `LastRow` help you included.


Also, when the data is imported both rows 1 & 3 are empty due to the export from PowerShell.  I delete Row 1 & shift up, which changes Row 3 to Row 2 and then delete the updated Row 2.

I'll play with the `Rows().EntireRow.Delete` snippet and see if I can get it to skip row 2 and delete 1 & 3 simultaneously.

Comment: Okay, so am I missing something to make a new paragraph and linebreak in the comment section here?

Comment: If it's on purpose then you can't have one code line (as this is a "multiple" selection). See edit